# How do you correct ApexCharts datetime range on X axis?

Tags: javascript, date, charts, apexcharts, x-axis

I've created a Line graph using Apexcharts in vanilla javascript. The series values have corresponding dates, but for some reason, the month of march is left out of the x axis date labels.

The sample data:

```
  series: [
    {
      name: "Parker, D (1250)",
      data: [
        { x: "28-Feb-2017 GMT", y: 34 },
        { x: "31-Mar-2017 GMT", y: 43 },
        { x: "30-Apr-2017 GMT", y: 31 },
        { x: "31-May-2017 GMT", y: 43 },
        { x: "30-Jun-2017 GMT", y: 33 },
        { x: "31-Jul-2017 GMT", y: 52 }
      ]
    }
```

The output:

[image]

For some reason, the chart is plotting the first data point (with date of 28th of Feb) directly above the date 1st of Feb. The expected behaviour that I would like is the date axis to say 1st of March instead.

Here's the codepen for anyone to have a play with: https://codepen.io/shane-wood/pen/zYpGxrY?editors=0010

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was observing similar issue on my side. You probably have issues with timezones, please double check from that point. Also there were few Apexchart issues with chart showing wrong timezone, which could be configurable in charts options.

Please check
https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/958
https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/110